# Java: How to login to a website

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to login to a website with a program. I googled alot, but the way other people do it somehow doesn't work for me.

Steps to login to the site are as following:

> get a PHPSESSID by requesting the auth.php
>
> send a post-request with PHPSESSID as cookie + content with username & password

I used burp-suite to see the packets sent and received throughout that process.

Getting the PHPSESSID is pretty straight forward, setting the Cookie and sending a post request wasn't that hard either, but the response is not the same.

```
String site = "The Site(Https://....)";
    URL myUrl = new URL(site);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
    //Get the PHPSESSID
    for(Entry<String, List<String>>  e : headers.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
    }
    List<String> ff = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
    String asd = ff.get(0);
    String[] temp = asd.split(";");
    asd = temp[0];
    System.out.println(asd);
    con.disconnect();
    
    myUrl = new URL(site);
    con = null;
    con = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "The host");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://ericsson.mareksokol.info/auth.php");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", asd);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +login.length());
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
            con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(login); //login is just copy&pasted from burp-suite
        wr.close();
    System.out.println("\n");
    
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); //
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(line);
      response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    System.out.println(response);
```

This is my first time working with a website and logging into it, I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: I think you should `close()` the connection variable before you open another one rather than set it to null.

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried to use `close()`, but there is no such function

Comment: `con.close()` should exist

Comment: @cricket_007 Even the javadoc to `HttpUrlConnection` says that there is a `disconnect()` method for the connection itself and a `close()` method for their input/output streams

Comment: Hmm. My bad, thought it implemented Closable. Alright, then the problem may lay in using the same Connection variable to do subsequent requests. If not, then the POST request isn't doing what you want, maybe. Have you tried using a tool like Postman to make a similar POST?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use one of HTTP client libraries for Java: Apache Httpclient, OKHttp etc.
If you want to do it with plain `Connection` object (note this example is for Plain Authentication scheme), you could do it like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class HttpBasicAuth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL ("http://ip:port/login");
            String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("test1:test1");

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in   = 
                new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you edit your response to show me how you'd handle 2 consecutive requests(pref. a GET followed by a POST request)